# Setting color in constants file is not being applied

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, constants

I'm trying to set a global primary color (yellow in this case) when starting my app. If no color is given, then the default color should be used (red in this case). Currently even when setting the color to yellow, it stays red.
I've removed the redundant code, to cancel out noise.

```
// index.js
import { setColorOptions } from './src/assets/style/style.constants';

export const initialize = config => {
  const {
    primaryColor,
  } = { ...config };

  setColorOptions(primaryColor);
  registerScreens(screens);

  Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
    goToLogin();
  });
};

initialize({
  primaryColor: 'yellow',
});
```

Then in my style.constants I have

```
//style.constants.js
export const COLOR = {
  PRIMARY: 'red',
};

export const setColorOptions = ( primaryColor) => {
  COLOR.PRIMARY = primaryColor || COLOR.PRIMARY;
};
```

And I am using COLOR.PRIMARY in my component like so

```
// Avatar component
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import * as S from '../assets/style/style.constants';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  avatarContainer: {
    backgroundColor: S.COLOR.PRIMARY, // this still is red
  },
});

export const Avatar = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(S.COLOR.PRIMARY); // logs yellow
  }, []);
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.avatarContainer}>
        <Text>OP </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.user.user,
});

export const AvatarComponent = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {},
)(Avatar);
```

However, when I define the color directly onto my component it works as it should be, like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={toggle}
    style={[styles.avatarContainer, { backgroundColor: S.COLOR.PRIMARY }]} // this is yellow now
>
```

Of course, I don't want to have it inline, but in the `StyleSheet` as shown in the first example. What am I missing or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The components depend on the constants and the »main/index« entry point on the components. So the dependency Tree looks like this:

```
constants
    |
components
    |
  index
```

So in the very Moment

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  avatarContainer: {
    backgroundColor: S.COLOR.PRIMARY, // this still is red
  },
});
```

is decleared within the component, the call to `initialize()` hasn't been made yet, so the value of `S.COLOR.PRIMARY` is still red. The order of execution is in your way here.

Even if the following explanation is *technically not correct*, you can *think of it* as follows: When loading the script, the browser internally assembles all the imports to a single script which could be thought like this:

```
//contents of constants
(() => {
  export const COLOR = {…
})();

//content of a component
(() => {
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({…
})();

//content of entry Point
(() => {
  //run that…
})()
```

SO as you can see, `StyleSheet.create({})` is called right away, before the entry point is executed, just where the value is changed.

To come around this, this simplest thing is to pass the styles as parameter to the component like that:

```
const Avatar = ({styles, ...props}) => <div style={{ … }}></div>
```

This way the component's style can change and even multiple components with different styles are possible.

Comment: I'm not at a laptop currently to try it. However isn't the component only being loaded after I call the `goToLogin()`. This also doesn't explain the correct yellow log shown in the `useEffect` as this is being handled as a 'componentDidMount'

Comment: no. use effect is called later. the stylesheet is created, right after the source file is loaded.

Comment: Tried it, and indeed you are right! That is the issue exactly! 
Any idea how I can work around it and solve this issue?

Comment: Hand in the config a parameter to the component.

Comment: How would I call the component then? We always inject a component this way `<Avatar prop1='string' prop2=true />`

Comment: you can choose as you like, I guess I would do some like this: `<Avatar style={{ color: '#00ff00'  }} />` Or, if you have a `styles` object, you can as well `<Avatar {...styles}` />, but than each style property becomes a »dedicated« property…

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be a matter of sequence of execution.

You can try change this

```js
export const Avatar = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(S.COLOR.PRIMARY); 
  }, []);
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.avatarContainer}>
        <Text>OP </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  avatarContainer: {
    backgroundColor: S.COLOR.PRIMARY, 
  },
});
```

Comment: I need to set it in the root page. The purpose of it is that you call initialize () with a color and the whole app changes the color based on the config you gave it. So I don't understand your solution. As I don't want to have it onPress. I also don't understand why you are suggesting to delete setColorOptions () from my index

Comment: Even if you invoke the function on the root page and you bring in the 'constants', its color will not change unless you run OnPress and reset the color because it refers to the initialized value of the root page.

Comment: Anywhere you need a place to call the `SetColorOptions` function. The color needs to be reset. You have already reset the `Red` value to `Yellow` on the root page.

Comment: I think your are still missing the point of what I am trying to achieve. That's what I want. I need the color to be Yellow every where and not red. It only needs to be red when initialize is called without a primaryColor, then it should default everywhere to red. But now even when I pass in the Yellow color, the red one is being shown, while I am expecting to show yellow. Check the comments in my code.

Comment: I've changed the intro of the question a bit, to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: Oh, I was mistaken. I left my thoughts in the answer.